# In Flutter Desktop, DropDownButton is restricted to the window size. Can we let it overflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am working on a desktop app with Flutter. This application runs as a small dialog on the screen with a dropdown list. I expect the height of the dropdown list to be larger than the dialog's height. In such a case, I want the dropdown list to overflow beyond the window size.

However, it is restricted to the dialog's height, and I cannot let it overflow beyond the size of the container window.

This was possible with traditional frameworks like Java Swing and C#. Is there a way to get this working with Flutter?

Is it possible to have a Flutter widget grow out of the parent?

[image]

Implemented with Java Swing:

[image]

Here is my Flutter code:

```dart
class _WorkingTaskState extends State<WorkingTask> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton2<String>(
      value: taskList.first["id"],
      buttonWidth: 300,
      dropdownMaxHeight: 600,
      items: taskList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((e) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: e["id"],
          child: Text(e["name"]),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Flutter can only render on its main window. You need to use native operating system components. Check out these packages.

- [native context menu](https://pub.dev/packages/native_context_menu)
- [contextual menu](https://pub.dev/packages/contextual_menu)
- [desktop context menu](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_context_menu)